# How do I MOQ the System.IO.FileInfo class... or any other class without an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, interface, moq

I am writing a number of unit tests for a logger class I created and I want to simulate the file class.  I can't find the interface that I need to use to create the MOQ... so how do you successfully MOQ a class without an interface?

It also isn't clear to me how I can use dependency injection without having an interface available:

```
private FileInfo _logFile;

public LogEventProcessorTextFile(FileInfo logFile) {
    _logFile = logFile;
}
```

When I really want to do something like this (note IFileInfo instead of FileInfo):

```
private IFileInfo _logFile;

public LogEventProcessorTextFile(IFileInfo logFile) {
    _logFile = logFile;
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to moq the file class? It is static, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo... has been corrected now to FileInfo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [SystemWrapper](https://github.com/jozefizso/SystemWrapper), a library which provides interfaces and mockable wrappers classes for many .NET classes which don't implement interfaces themselves.

Comment: Why use extra third party libraries for the purpose of unit testing ??

Answer (score 35):

Design your code so that instead of accessing the `FileInfo` class directly, access an interface (named for example `IFileInfo`) with the same capabilities. In production code you will use a class that just delegates all its functionality to the system `FileInfo` class, but for unit testing you can mock the interface.

For example, in an application I made that acted differently depending on the current date, I declared the following interface:

```
interface IDateTimeProvider
{
    DateTime Today();
}
```

And the production class was just:

```
class DateTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider
{
    public DateTime Today()
    {
        return DateTime.Today;
    }
}
```

You can complement this approach with the usage of a dependency injection engine to decide whether a real class or a mock should be used in each case.

Comment: I'm definitely 100% for the idea of use interfaces and using dependency injection, but my issue was not being able to find the interface for FileInfo... are you saying that I should create an interface that matches my usage of FileInfo?  If so how can I have FileInfo 'inherit' (sorry if that's incorrect terminology usage when applied to what I'm asking) my interface without having access to its source?

Comment: You wouldn't have FileInfo inherit your new interface. Instead, you wrap FileInfo in your own class that does implement the interface. For more info, see the section "Wrap infrastructure that cannot be mocked" from this page: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/gabrielschenker/archive/2009/02/27/refactoring-legacy-code.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... it helped me understand the 'gateway pattern' which is clearly the way to handle the situation in my question. If you aren't familar with the SystemWrapper library that wcoenen pointed me in the direction of... you should definitely check it out... it turns out to be exactly what I needed.  But thank your for your input it was incredibly valuable to me.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following nuget package to your csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Abstractions" Version="13.2.29" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Inject *System.IO.Abstractions.FileSystem* into your class:

```
  public class FileLogger
  {
    private readonly IFileSystem fileSystem;

    public FileLogger(System.IO.Abstractions.IFileSystem fileSystem) // new FileSystem()
    {
      this.fileSystem = fileSystem ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileSystem));
    }
    
    public void LogEventProcessorTextFile(string filePath)
    {
      IFileInfo fileInfo = fileSystem.FileInfo.FromFileName(filePath);

      LogEventProcessorTextFile(fileInfo);
    }

    private System.IO.Abstractions.IFileInfo _logFile;

    public void LogEventProcessorTextFile(IFileInfo logFile) {
      _logFile = logFile;
    }
  }
```

Moq examples:

```
private Mock<IFileSystem> FileSystemMock { get; set; }

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
  var file = Mock.Of<IFileInfo>();
  var directoryInfo = Mock.Of<IDirectoryInfo>();

  Mock.Get(file).Setup(c => c.Exists).Returns(true);

  FileSystemMock = new Mock<IFileSystem>();

  FileSystemMock.Setup(c => c.FileInfo.FromFileName(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(file);
  FileSystemMock.Setup(c => c.DirectoryInfo.FromDirectoryName("Settings")).Returns(directoryInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help you to ease the creation of wrapper classes for static or non-mockable 3rd party classes. This tool will generated Interface and a concrete wrapper class of any existing class such as System.IO right on your Visual Studio Project.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Digitrish.WrapperGenerator/

Answer (score 0):

This is more limited in that you can only use exact files, but can also be good because you control exactly what is in your file for the unit test....You could create a folder in your unit test project to keep pretend log files in. Then get current directory in your unit test using:

```
var currentDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

then hop one level down into your test folder and grab the test files with:

```
var testFileInfos = Directory.GetFiles(
    Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "testFolderName"));
```

Then use those `FileInfo` objects as needed in your tests.