# Unit testing a time - based component?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datetime

So I'm writing a cache system (not too complicated, but it has very nice semantics) with a ttl (time to live) for items.

Of course the ttl must be unit tested, but since one can't inject a new implementaton of "IDateTime" or "ITimeSpan" in C# (because there is no such thing), how would you go about that?

Write a new component "IDateTimeProvider" and "DateTimeProvider" first, which one can mockup then?

Isn't reimplementing parts of the .NET runtime library... overkill?

Edit: Thank you all for your amazing answers! I know now exactly what I'm going to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to see this question:

[How do I MOQ the System.IO.FileInfo class... or any other class without an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582596/how-do-i-moq-the-system-io-fileinfo-class-or-any-other-class-without-an-interf)

In a nutshell you'll either need to make a wrapper class yourself, or use a library that already provides wrapper classes for DateTime, like [SystemWrapper](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/wikipage).

Comment: In other words, no, it's not overkill.  When the client code is not testable, you have to do what you have to do.

Answer (score 6):

I usually use a variation of [Ayende's solution](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/07/Dealing-with-time-in-tests.aspx).

```
public static class SystemTime
{
    public static Func<DateTime> DateProvider = () => DateTime.Now;

    public static DateTime Now { get { return DateProvider(); } }
}
```

In the code under test you can now use SystemTime.Now to get the current time:

```
var currentTime = SystemTime.Now;
```

And in the test you can set the current time to a known value:

```
SystemTime.DateProvider = () => new DateTime(2010,6,25);
```

Comment: This might fail when running tests in parallel. I prefer to use a wrapper like `IDateTimeProvider`, as others suggested.

Answer (score 4):

how would writing an IDateTimeProvider be reimplementing parts of the .Net Framework?

You'd just have two implementations, one that returns DateTime.Now and another that returns a value you specified before.

Comment: The important part being that you're not reimplementing most of DateTime at all - you're *only* extracting out the "current time" part.

Answer (score 2):

An IDateTime provider might prove useful in other ways -- if your cache is to be used between client and server apps running on separate machines, you will one one single time-source for both machines (usually the server) otherwise the times may be out of step.
I you use the IDateTimeProvider interface everywhere, then the client can use a version that gets the time from the server.

You would get that *plus* the Unit-testing de-coupling.

Answer (score 2):

If you're having trouble inventing some mockup object, I think it'ld be good to rethink the testability of your component.

Maybe the ttl logic should be testable on it's own, somewhat like this:

```
TTLlogic l = new TTLLogic( 10 );
DateTime startdate = now();
Object item=new String();
l.addItem( startdate, item );

l.setTime( startdate.addSeconds( 5 ) );
assert( l.items().contains( item ) );

l.setTime( startdate.addSeconds( 10 ) );
assert( l.items().empty() );
```