# Need to Mock Url.RouteUrl for Unit Test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have following line of code in my Controller/Action

```
var defaultRoute = Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { action = "MyAction", controller = "MyController", id = 1 });
```

I am writing a Unit Test and Need to Mock this line to make it return some URL. I am not getting how i can do so. Can anyone help me to write a Test for this Line.

THanks

Comment: What's the Work Around? How i can make my Unit Test Ignore Url.RouteUrl Line

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a thread related to your problem: [How do I MOQ the System.IO.FileInfo class... or any other class without an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582596/how-do-i-moq-the-system-io-fileinfo-class-or-any-other-class-without-an-inter)

The problem is that you can't mock classes that don't implement an interface or have the respective method/property set to virtual.

Comment: What's the Work Around? How i can make my Unit Test Ignore Url.RouteUrl Line

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a wrapper class for the untestable one, and then mock that:

```
public interface IUrlRouterWrapper
{
    // Put any methods you want to mock here...
    void RouteUrl(string routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
}

public class UrlRouterWrapper : IUrlRouterWrapper
{
    // ... and implement them here, calling through to the real, non-testable class.
    public void RouteUrl(string routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
    {
        Url.RouteUrl(routeName, routeValues);
    }
}
```

And then in your code that uses RouteUrl:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    private readonly IUrlRouterWrapper _urlRouterWrapper;

    public SomeOtherClass(IUrlRouterWrapper urlRouterWrapper)
    {
        _urlRouterWrapper = urlRouterWrapper;
    }

    public void DoThings()
    {
        // ...
        _urlRouterWrapper.WrapUrl("Default", new { action = "MyAction", controller = "MyController", id = 1 });
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now you have an easily-mockable interface, `IUrlRouterWrapper`, that you can test to your heart's content.